# Clojure Successive Powers

Tags: clojure

How would a programmer go along to yield successive powers of two starting at 1 up to a limit?

I saw the documentation http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/iterate but still need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Separate the task into two steps.

IF you first create a lazy infinite (no need to decide in advance the maximum power you'll need) sequence of powers of 2, you can subsequently slice and dice it any way you choose

`(def powers-of-2 (iterate (partial *' 2) 2))`

To get the first n powers

`(take 5 powers-of-2)`

To get the powers less than 70

`(take-while (partial > 70) powers-of-2)`

Added:

Actually I prefer the more general form:

`(defn powers-of [n] (iterate (partial *' n) n))`

`(take 5 (powers-of 2))`

As well as being more general, unless you have efficiency concerns, by calling the higher order function each time for a new lazy sequence you avoid holding on to the head and allow the memory to be garbage collected.

Comment: +1 for the (iterate...) version.  It would be even better with *' instead of * to handle arithmetic overflows.

Comment: oops, added that to my first example and then forgot it when adding the general form. Edited answer. Thanks.

Comment: Based on subsequent question asked, to start the powers of two from an exponent of 0, change the second argument to iterate from a 2 to a 1. To limit the number of powers to the nth exponent use the "take" form e.g. (take 71 powers-of-2)

Comment: Even the specialized powers-of-2 form should be a (no-argument) defn, not a def. Otherwise the sequence can never get garbage collected, and attempting to find the ten billionth power of two might run you out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` form:

```
(def powers (for [x (range)] 
                 (java.lang.Math/pow 2 x)))

(take 10 powers)
(1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0 16.0 32.0 64.0 128.0 256.0 512.0)
```

Comment: but up to a specific number that number of choice. For example, (powers-of-two 70 (fn [p] (println "The power of two's are " p))

Comment: @user1585646 - if you keep correcting people's answers, perhaps you should revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
(defn powers-of-two
  [n]
  (map ; we are mapping over a sequence 
    (comp int #(Math/pow 2 %)) ; a composition of two functions
                               ; Math/pow returns doubles so int is used to make them into integers
    (range 1 (inc n)))) ; a sequence from 1 to 10

(powers-of-two 15) ;=> (2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768)
```

Comment: but up to a specific number of choice. For example, (powers-of-two 70 (fn [p] (println "The power of two's are " p))

Comment: @user1585646 You can put it in a function. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to interpret "limit", and from your question it is not sure which one you mean.

Also, you say "starting at 1 up to a limit". Do you mean "start at 0^2 (which is 1) up to a limit", or "start at 1^2 (which is 2)"? In the examples below I'm assuming you want to start with 0^2. If you want to start with 1^2, replace `(range)` with `(drop 1 (range))` in the code below.

In the first interpretation, "limit" means "give me a sequence of n elements, where the elements are the successive powers of two". Ankur and others showed how to do that:

```
;; return the sequence (0^2, 1^2, 2^2 ... 149^2) 
(take 150 (for [x (range)] (java.lang.Math/pow 2 x)))
; => (1.0 2.0 4.0 8.0 ..... 7.1362384635297994E44)

;; this is functionally equivalent:
(for [x (range 150)] (java.lang.Math/pow 2 x))
```

The other interpretation is "give me a sequence of successive powers of two that are smaller than the limit". You could do that with the following:

```
;; return the sequence (0^2, 1^2, 2^2 ... 2^7)
(for [x (range) :let [r (Math/pow 2 x)] :while (< r 150)] r)
; => (2.0 4.0 8.0 16.0 32.0 64.0 128.0)
```